# "Etiam si omnes" and "Et si omnes"

Tags: semantics

Is there a semantic difference between **"Etiam si omnes, ego non"** and **"Et si omnes ego non"**?

I know Latin is loose when it comes to word order, and it seems to me the answer is no, but the way this sentence is worded [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiam_si_omnes,_ego_non) has me wondering if the uncommon "Et si omnes" changes the meaning in any way:

> A variant is Et si omnes ego non, as written on the door of Philipp von Boeselager's home, **highlighting the necessity of maintaining one's own opinion and moral judgment, even in the face of a differing view held by the majority** (in particular, it refers to von Boeselager's dissent and resistance against Hitler during the Nazi dictatorship).

The original, common "Etiam si omnes, ego non" also **highlights the necessity of maintaining one's own opinion and moral judgment, even in the face of a differing view held by the majority**. Any difference, or poor wording?

*[Note: I am not asking if there is a big difference in the meanings, which there is not, but if there is a very fine, nuanced difference in the semantic stress of the sentence, created by the very fine, nuanced difference in the Latin]*

Comment: My intuition would say there is little difference, possibly with some extra emphasis in *etiam*.

Comment: Related: [How often is “et” used as an adverb, and what might distinguish that usage?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)

Comment: Dear @Cerberus I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: @Johan88: Dear Alex, thank you for your kind words. I can only say that I am rather busy, and I'm not sure what exactly this entails, what you'd like me to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common phrase is *etiam si* (even if), but *et* can be used as a shorthand for *etiam*, which would be the only reasonable way of reading it in that sentence. So, there is no significant difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks. You're quite right, but I'm not looking for a *"significant difference"*. **If** there is any difference I think it would be a highly nuanced one, a very fine stressing of one semantic over another.

Comment: Length is the only difference.